# vector or array value insertion

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have a variable
 `long long int alpha;` 
This `alpha` is basically 8 bytes 
but I wish the byte size can be decided dynamically by input to the function. 
So that it could be inserted to `char*` array.

If there is a function

```
int putInput(int sizeOfAlpha){
    long long int alpha;
    char* beta = (char*)malloc(128);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 128 ; i++){
        ... alpha calculation ...
        beta[i*sizeOfAlpha] = alpha; // This is also wrong
    }
}
```

Then the size of alpha has to be modified by `sizeOfAlpha`

For instance if `sizeOfAlpha` is `2` in decimal,

and if `alpha` is `0x00 00 00 00 00 00 04 20` in hex,

and if `i` is `0` 
,
then `beta[0]` should be `04` and `beta[1]` should be `20` in hex

if `alpha` is `0x00 00 00 00 00 00 42 AB` in hex,

and if `i` is `1` 
,
then `beta[2]` should be `42` and `beta[3]` should be `AB` in hex

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `std::vector<char> beta(sizeOfAlpha);` If you decide to use C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I can also use C++ but can you be more specific? Thank you

Comment: OK. Tag with the language you want to use. Then replace the dynamic array with a vector.

Comment: @juanchopanza Won't using `vector` be a big performance hit?

Comment: @juanchopanza ok Done

Comment: @meaning-matters No. And it cures the memory leak.

Comment: Should alpha be a signed integer ?

Comment: @quetin Would it matter?

Comment: Yes. The most straightforward way is to repeatedly shift `alpha` and store its bytes into successive slots of `beta`, but right-shifting signed integers is implementation-defined and may not fit the bill.

Comment: @Quentin it does not have to be signed. Can you show me how I can do that with shift?

Comment: @John Doyle Relative to your examples if i is 1  then why are beta[2] and beta[3] used instead of beta[1] and beta[2]?

Comment: @JohnDoyle Could you double-check your examples ? I'm unsure of what `i` and `sizeOfAlpha` do. Shouldn't the second one yield `beta[1] = 0x42`, `beta[2] = 0xAB` ?

Comment: @Quentin when `i` is 0, `beta[0*sizeOfAlpha] = 0x04 0x20` but since it is based on char, only 1 byte fits into array. So, beta[0] = 04, beta[1] = 20, and if `i` is 1, `beta[1*sizeOfAlpha] = 0x42 0xAB`. sizeOfAlpha is 2, so beta[2] = 0x42 and beta[3] = 0xAB.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Char is only 1 byte, and if 2 bytes have to fit into char[], I need 2 bytes. so beta[0] beta[1] (two bytes) has to be used to fit sizeOfAlpha. Thus, beta[0] and beta[1] are used for first alpha value calculation, and beta[2] and beta[3] are used for second alpha value calculation.

Comment: You are assigning a number to a char, which will always only write one byte (the exact result is implementation specific. I'd recommend using memcpy here insted of the assignment. Also the whole thing seems like a bad idea in general.

Comment: @MikeMB Totally forgot about memcpy! Thanks a loT! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `alpha` is unsigned :

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec(8);

for(std::size_t j = (i + 1u) * sizeOfAlpha - 1u; sizeOfAlpha; --j, --sizeOfAlpha) {
    vec[j] = alpha & 0xff;
    alpha >>= 8;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d217a1fa28b88348)